# Hijack Save command in RTE to perform pre-save (WikiPage)

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, rte

I'm doing some custom ribbon buttons (sandbox solution) to extend RTE in an Sharepoint Foundation 2010 environment.

For this i need to perform some actions on the RTE field using jquery before saving it to clean the code..

On List richtext fields i got it using the `presaveaction()` function to hold my js code, but for what i realized, this do not work on saving wikipages.

Any ideas? any RTE or CUI function that i can hijack to put my code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [onbeforeunload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) event can do that for you.

Keep in mind that this will only work if your code is synchronous.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.log('insert your code here');
};
```

If that is no option for you, heres a small untested hack:

```
if(CoreInvoke){
    _baseCoreInvoke = CoreInvoke;
    CoreInvoke = function(task, target){
        if(target.getAttribute('_action') === 'save'){
            console.log('your code here');
        }
        // call original function
        _baseCoreInvoke.apply(window, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks MX, onBeforeUnload almost worked, tryed it checking typeof(RTE) != 'undefined' to see if leaving the editmode, but got some problems when adding webparts , it fired too.. but found other way..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, find another way. Hijacked the

```
 SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallback
```

Worked till now, doing more tests.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(hooksave, 'SP.js');
function hooksave() {
if (
  (typeof(SP.Application)!="undefined")&&
  (typeof(SP.Application.UI)!="undefined")&&
  (typeof(SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor)!="undefined")&&
  (typeof(SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallback)!="undefined")
  )
 {
  SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallbackOrig = SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallback;
  SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallback =
  function() { 
    alert('Saving');
    this.savingPageCallbackOrig(); 
   };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, neither overriding `SP.Application.UI.WikiPageNameInPlaceEditor.prototype.savingPageCallback`, `CoreInvoke` or using `onbeforeunload` allowed me to edit wiki content before saving.

But using this method I could (SharePoint 2013 and Enterprise Wiki Page):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    var originalCallCommandHandler = CUI.Page.CommandDispatcher.prototype.callCommandHandler;
    CUI.Page.CommandDispatcher.prototype.callCommandHandler = function (handler, commandId, properties, sequenceNumber) {
        //"PageStateGroupSaveSplit" is passed either when pressing Page -> Edit in ribbon or Save when in edit mode. Presence of RTE object means we are in Edit mode.
        var saveCommands = ["PageStateGroupSaveSplit", "PageStateGroupSave", "PageStateGroupSaveAndPublish"];
        if (saveCommands.indexOf(commandId) > -1 && typeof RTE !== "undefined") {
            var currentEditableRegion = RTE.Canvas.currentEditableRegion();
            //Do something with currentEditableRegion 

            RTE.RichTextEditor.transferContentsToInputField(currentEditableRegion.id);
        }
        return originalCallCommandHandler(handler, commandId, properties, sequenceNumber);
    }
}, "cui.js");
```